# How better can I describe this gesture?

Tags: phrases, expressions, synonyms, gestures

I am trying to find a more "optimised" way to say the below. Edna feels that Felix is being condescending but he is not so he shows it through his gesture but the whole thing feels very clunky...very clinical. Is there a better way to frame Felix's gesture ?

> Like a library ? Edna arched an eyebrow, wondering if Felix was being condescending.
>
> Felix raised his hands, displaying open palms, to show that he did not mean it. That would help.

Comment: I just know someone will try "jazz hands".

Comment: Jazz hands perhaps?

Comment: Goddammit!..... :P

Comment: Felix [raised his hands](https://as2.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/10/63/83/500_F_210638389_FqgbtDraDTz6QU9TkGjPsyQJ7LkxLDHQ.jpg) **in surrender**.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Surrender would be acknowledging that he meant the condescension but it was not implied by him...

Comment: I think what you have is pretty good.

Comment: This is definitely *not* jazz hands! "Jazz hands" is a movement as much as a gesture. It involves shaking the hands while they are raised. It can indicate applause, showing off or cheesy enjoyment.  Completely inappropriate for this context.  "Surrender" is much better.

Comment: @user96551 not really, it's more a gesture of apology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A gesture of appeasement**

> Felix raised his hands, displaying open palms, to show that he did not
> mean it. That would help.

There is nothing wrong with your original sentence. If you want an alternative, maybe:

*Felix raised his hands in a gesture of appeasement, to show that he did not mean it. That would help.*

or

*Felix raised his open palms in a gesture of appeasement. That would help.*

or

*Felix held up his open palms, signalling appeasement. That would help.*